# Mockito always return NULL when test hibernate method

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, junit, mockito

I have some hibernate methods and when i test them, mockito always return null instead of expected value

This is my hibernate method

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public StudentDAO() {

}
public List<StudentDetail> listStudentDetail() {
    String hql = "Select new " + StudentDetail.class.getName() //
            + "(s.studentid,s.name,s.address) " //
            + " from " + Student.class.getName() + " s ";
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query<StudentDetail> query = session.createQuery(hql, StudentDetail.class);
    List<StudentDetail> list =null;
    list = query.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

And this is my test method

```
@Mock
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Mock
Query query;
@Mock
Session session;
@Mock
List<StudentDetail> list;
@InjectMocks
private StudentDAO studentDAO ;

// Test get method

@Test
public void getListStudentTest() {
    StudentDetail sd1 = new StudentDetail(1, "A", "X");
    Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);
    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    Mockito.verify(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
    Mockito.verify(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyObject() ));
    Mockito.verify(query.getResultList());

    Assert.assertEquals(sd1, studentDAO.listStudentDetail().get(0));
}
```

When i run my web app, `studentDAO.listStudentDetail()` return true value normally but in test method its always return null

Comment: i am not sure but you are mocking the wrong `createQuery` method or? In your code you use this with 2 arguments and in your mock is only one

Comment: i have fixed it, but mock still return null :((

Comment: @NguyễnVũHoàng Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
Assert.assertEquals(sd1, studentDAO.listStudentDetail().get(0));
```

the `studentDAO.listStudentDetail()` returns a mock list. You didn't mock its `.get` method. Thus it returns `null` by default.
You should modify your `assertEquals` check:

```
Assert.assertEquals(list, studentDAO.listStudentDetail());
```

(You don't need the `sd1` object at all)

---

Also you are not using `verify` properly. You should do like this:

```
Mockito.verify(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession();
Mockito.verify(session).createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());
Mockito.verify(query).getResultList();
```

(note the closing parenthesis before `.`)

Comment: It still doesnt work, i tried this yesterday :( there are more some errors like `wanted but not invoked`

Comment: *Wanted, but not invoked* is related to `verify` methods. You can comment those lines and focus on `assert` first.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at method that you mock

```
Mockito.when(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(query);
```

and method that you call:

```
 Query<StudentDetail> query = session.createQuery(hql, StudentDetail.class);
```

they have different arrity (number of arguments). You mock method with one argument, and call with two. Mock, when don't know what should return, return `null`.

---

Edit:

```
@Mock
List<StudentDetail> list;

//....

Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);
```

How you initialize and fill list? BTW, better (in my opinion) version of that code:

```
@Mock
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Mock
Query query;
@Mock
Session session;

@InjectMocks
private StudentDAO studentDAO ;

// Test get method

@Test
public void getListStudentTest() {
    StudentDetail sd1 = new StudentDetail(1, "A", "X");

    List<StudentDetail> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(sd1);

    Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);
    Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    Mockito.verify(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
    Mockito.verify(session.createQuery(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyObject() ));
    Mockito.verify(query.getResultList());

    Assert.assertEquals(sd1, studentDAO.listStudentDetail().get(0));
}
```

Now we mock external/framework resources (`SessionFactory`, `Session`, `Query`) and manually manage our data.

Comment: i have fixed it, but mock still return null :((